# Detect red X event in Safari extension

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, safari-extension

Is it possible to use JavaScript in order to listen for the event when a user clicks the 'red x' in Safari rather than 'quit'. This script must run in the global page of an extension.

Comment: You could try listening for the window "close" event and check again after an interval to see if the application is still running. It's not perfect but I think that's the only way

Comment: The "close", "unload" and similar events are not called when the red x is clicked. It's problematic.